# Google Data Studio Pivot Table - Adding Multiple Months (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

As you can see from the below picture,

I am able to insert the pivot table with Default Channel Grouping as the Row Dimension and Month as the column Dimension and metric as users.

I would like to add more months (in columns) like, Nov, Oct, etc.

I would like to add more months in the column. (Now in the pic as you see, I am able to extract only Jan and December month data).

I have also attached the Settings / configuration for this report. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you adjust the chart's date range to a custom date range, then it will include the further months within the adjusted date range.
[image]

There is a current known issue in Data Studio affecting column sort.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146886718

I found using the dimension Month of Year worked when sorting column order

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the issue was resolved earlier this month (seems to be a bug fix that was part of the 13 Feb 2020 update which also included the functionality to [filter reports by an email field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/28627919)).